# Linux kernel issue when booting from U-Boot on Cortex-A15 CPU QEMU

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu, u-boot, cortex-a, omap

I am trying to run u-boot to boot Linux kernel on qemu vexpress-a15. The U-Boot and Linux kernel are configured to run on TI OMAP5, which has ARM Cortex A-15. So I have done some modification (uart, spi,i2c,..) and already booted the linux kernel from u-boot. The problem is that qemu didn't run as I expected. It doesn't show the usual first line "Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0" (loglevel command line is already set to 8). Does the revision of arm cpu matter? I figured out that qemu created Cortex-A15 rev r4p0 with different to the cpu from my board Cortex-A15 rev r2p2.

[First line of linux kernel log message]    (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cyJ2.png)

[End line of linux kernel log message]    (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgVmq.png)

[qemu gdb backtrace]    (https://i.stack.imgur.com/v13vP.png)

I would really appreciate any thought or advice.

Comment: "*It doesn't show the usual first line ...*" -- Umm, if you scrutinize the boot log, there's a salient message about `1781 printk messages dropped`. So is not just the "*first line*". Seems like the kernel boot failed before the serial console was properly initialized, so the syslog was never displayed. This is a situation that the **earlycon** or **earlyprintk** capability is meant for.

Comment: Hi, I added the earlyprintk into the kernel command line. It actually showed some log messages which have been missed before. But it still showed nearly 800 printk messages dropped. Anyway, thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. Appending kernel boot command line with "log_buf_len=1M", no more messages dropped.